# how can i change focus of kendo datePicker on another button? i

Tags: javascript, api, model-view-controller

i use change property and close property but apparently Kendo date picker have problem with them
i use `onselect` too,  but nothing is working

```
$("#txtFromDate").kendoDatePicker({
            format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
});

//$('#txtFromDate').trigger('change', function (e) {
//    $('#btnNewRanges').focus();
//});`enter code here`
```

Comment: please review your questions and if there is some post that answers your question, mark it as accepted by click on check-mark near the answer. Also remove those posts which you think may not be useful for future readers. Also you can post answer to your own questions if you have found an answer. Having lot's of unanswered questions or unaccepted answers  may decrease your chance to receive good answers in future.

Comment: Also it's better to do something in response of answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#events-change) event when you initialize the date picker :

```
$("#txtFromDate").kendoDatePicker({
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
        change: function(){
             // Your date picker changed, handle accordingly
             $('#btnNewRanges').focus();
        }
});
```

Likewise, if you need to subscribe to the event later (i.e. post-initialization), you can use the `bind()` function to wire up the event :

```
$("#txtFromDate").data("kendoDatePicker").bind("change", function() {
      // Your date picker changed, handle accordingly
      $('#btnNewRanges').focus();
});
```